# Make page numbers stand out from PDF background

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages

I am compiling a document from many full-page PDFs and add a table of contents. Because the PDFs are full page, the page number might not stand out from the background. Is there a good way to make them stand out? (I would prefer not to scale the included pages down to make room for the footer because some pages already have some pretty small print.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\includepdfset{noautoscale=true, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents    

\section{Documents}
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={
      1, subsection,1,One,h1,
      2, subsection,1,Two,h2,
      3, subsection,1,Three,h3
    }]{blahblah.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on how (design wise) it should look? (For example have the page number in a colored box.)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246712/wrap-page-number-in-colored-box-in-footer and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202900/rectangle-as-background-for-header?s=7|23.5585 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252444/custom-footer-using-tikz

Comment: @TorbjørnT. A white box that masks the background would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a new page style with `fancyhdr` and place the page number in a `\fcolorbox` with white fill.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{pageno}{
\setlength\fboxsep{5pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\fcolorbox{white}{white}{\thepage}}
}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\includepdfset{noautoscale=true, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{pageno}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents    

\section{Documents}
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={
      1, subsection,1,One,h1,
      2, subsection,1,Two,h2,
      3, subsection,1,Three,h3
    }]{blahblah.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a simple yet effective solution.

Comment: To set the frame of the box, I'm using `\setlength\fboxrule{0.2pt}` and `\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\thepage}`.