# How do I add a colored background behind page numbers?

Tags: formatting, page-numbering, backgrounds, embedding

I have a master document where I embed several pdf files that I need to present the case for my visa. Most of these pdfs are scanned pages and the page number is printed over some drawing or texts that don't allow proper reading of the number. What I want is to have a colored background (like a highlighting) only behind the page number. Is that possible?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages, xcolor, etoolbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\makeatletter
% patch the "plain" page style
%\patchcmd{\ps@plain}{\thepage}{\textcolor{red}{\thepage}}{}{}

%\usepackage{sectsty}
%\allsectionsfont{\color{blue}\underline}
%\sectionfont{\color{blue}\itshape\selectfont}
%\subsectionfont{\color{blue}\itshape\selectfont}

%\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
%\newpagestyle{main}[\small]{
    %\setheadrule{.55pt}%
    %\sethead[\colorbox{black}{\color{white}{\thepage}}]%   even-left
            %[\chaptertitle]%                               even-center
            %[\colorbox{CornflowerBlue}{\thesection}]%      even-right
            %{\colorbox{CornflowerBlue}{\thesection}}%      odd-left
            %{\sectiontitle}%                               odd-center
            %{\colorbox{black}{\color{red}{\thepage}}}%     odd-right
            %\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Letters of Recommendation}

\newpage

\subsection{first_letter}

\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}]{Letters/first_letter.pdf}

%blah, blah, blah, many more pages.

\end{document}

``
```

Comment: Welcome Gustavo! It seems to me that there is a very similar question with an answer already:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426004/make-page-numbers-stand-out-from-pdf-background

Comment: I tried that example and it didn't work. The page numbers are shown exactly the same as before. I even deleted all the auxiliary files and compiled again and still didn't work.

Comment: regarding the example under the link, you have to set your colours, e.g. `\fancyfoot[C]{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\thepage}}`